# Would it make sense to sell a stock, then repurchase it for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax

this would be a tax related question. I started graduate school this year and by the end of the year will have earned less than $15,000. I have couple stocks that I have held for several years that have appreciated 200%-300% in value since I bought them. Because my income is so low, would I benefit from selling stock X/Y, taking a $20-30K profit, then repurchasing the stock(s)? I really like the companies and their stock and when I first purchased them had seen them as 10+ year stocks to hold. I'm just wondering if I sold them now, instead of in a future year where they have theoretically gone up in value and where I would have a full-time income, if I would be saving myself from paying potential higher taxes on it in the future. The idea being that by repurchasing them and then selling in say 5 years from now, the percentage of gained income would be less. And I would be filing single

Does that make sense?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.kitces.com/blog/understanding-the-mechanics-of-the-0-long-term-capital-gains-tax-rate-how-to-harvest-capital-gains-for-a-free-step-up-in-basis/

Comment: Do you file single or married?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're talking about is called "tax gain harvesting," and it is considered good tax management.

From The Oblivious Investor, [investors in the 10% or 15% bracket pay 0% tax on long-term capital gains](http://www.obliviousinvestor.com/tax-gain-harvesting/).

For an interesting take on [never paying income taxes again](http://www.gocurrycracker.com/never-pay-taxes-again/), check out Go Curry Cracker. You can claim up to $70,000 or so in capital gains before paying any taxes if you are the 10% or 15% tax bracket.

Comment: [In the UK and elsewhere in Europe, such transactions are called "bed and breakfasting".](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/manuals/cgmanual/cg13350.htm)